# Different format of data coming from 'input' vs. 'textarea'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React Bootstrap but have been trying to adhere to the official documentation, such as: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-control-props

In one modal I've added an `input` textbox and a `textarea` textbox via the `Form.Control` approach.  That's all good

What's strange is that the data coming back from the `onInput` event handler is different for each.  With the first one, it's pure characters.  With the second, it's characters in quotation marks.

Not a big problem but I'm curious if this is deliberate behavior or a known bug for shouldn't they both be in quotes or both not?

```
<Form.Control id='companyName' 
              data-testid='companyName' 
              as='input' 
              onInput={e => addFleetCustomer(e.target.value, null)}
/>

<Form.Control id='companyNotes'
              data-testid='companyNotes'
              as='textarea'
              rows='3'
              onInput={e => addFleetCustomer(null, e.target.value)      
/>
```